# Design pattern for plugin dependencies (similar to Nuget package dependencies)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, plugins

I'm developing an application that heavily relies on a plugin architecture (*).
However I'm not sure what design pattern to use for dependencies between plugins, e.g. when plugin A depends on plugin B, possibly with some constraints (plugin B version between v1.05 and v1.30 or so)

My thoughts so far:

1. I could specify an interface for plugin B that never changes, and have plugin A reference this interface project only. Plugin B is then free to implement this in whatever way with versioning, and the latest available implementation will just be dependency-injected into the requested interfaces.
   This could work, but it seems as though defining an interface which is very much tailored to the specific plugin's functions is a bit unnecessary; plus I suppose that I'd have to stick to that interface then; I could only enhance the plugins implementation in future versions easily, but not the interface.
2. I could ignore interfaces and just develop the plugins' implentations. Plugin A's project could then directly reference Plugin B's .dll. But as far as I know, this would cause errors when replacing Plugin B's .dll with a newer version, unless I add explicit version redirects in my applications config, wouldn't it?!

Are there any best practices? I suppose this issue is very similar to Nuget packages' depdendencies - does anyone happen to know how they have solved it?

Thanks

---

(*) in case it matters, my plugin architecture works as follows: I have all my plugins implement an interface IPlugin.
My main app then scans the plugin directory for all .dlls, filters out all classes that implement IPlugin, and uses Ninject to add a binding from IPlugin to the specific implementation (in the end, there'll be several bindings available for IPlugin, e.g. IPlugin -> Plugin1, IPlugin -> Plugin2 etc.). I'm then using Ninject to request/create a singleton instance of each plugin and register it in my main app. That way, my plugins can "request" dependencies via constructor arguments and Ninject/DI takes care of providing those.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, Nuget tracks library dependencies using the metadata stored in the nuget package file.  If I were you I'd avoid implementing arbitrary restrictions.  What if one of your plugin developers wants to create a shared support library of useful classes, for example?

To my mind, a plugin should be a black box of functionality.  If a plugin needs another plugin, then they should communicate via a standardized messaging platform rather than directly.

That said, you could always scrape all interface implementations from the library you load and hook those up as well as your plugins.  That way the plugin developer can "request" implementations of those interfaces as well as plugins.

You'll need to cope with massive class libraries (I recommend only hooking up in Ninject interfaces that are referenced in plugin constructors) and with potential conflicts (two plugins might expect separate implementations of the same interface - which is the main reason I believe that a plugin should take care of itself internally, rather than hoping its design time expectations are fulfilled by the external plugin manager).

And in answer to (2), as long as the methods and properties you reference don't change name or signature, you shouldn't have any problems using a newer version of DLL B with DLL A.  If you change a return type, change from a public field (which shouldn't exist in the first place) to a public property, change the parameters on a method or anything of that nature on a class that you're using from DLL B in DLL A, a recompile of A would be required.